# Is libuv just a wrapper on libev on POSIX systems?

Tags: libuv, libev

I am really confused between libev and libuv.

Is libuv just a wrapper on libev on POSIX systems?

If not where does it differ?

Answer (score 2):

No longer, since libuv-v0.9

[Here is the libuv github issue](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/485) which tracked the removal of libev from libuv.

The reasons for removal are, to quote from the above linked issue:

> In case any project watchers are wondering, libev served us well but:
>
> 1. It only supports level-triggered I/O. On Linux, we want to use
>      edge-triggered mode - it cuts down the number of syscalls by a
>      substantial margin.
> 2. libev's inner loop does a lot of things we don't really need. Gutting
>      the inner loop like we did in [649ad50](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/commit/649ad50c328851444998e3d2dea66ba5b48fe64b) gave a 40% performance increase
>      on some benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, as of today, we still don't use edge-triggered I/O on Linux.